# Installing Windows clone on a Hybrid Drive

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, clone, hybrid-storage

I recently bought a Seagate Momentus XT (750 GB) Hybrid Drive. Before I took out my old hard drive I made a clone of my Windows partition and stored it on an external hard drive(I used partition wizard to copy the contents of my hard drive and dump them on the external drive, no disk image). After installing the new hard drive I put in a Gparted Live CD and copied the clone to a partition set up on my new Hybrid drive. I then made the freshly copied partition the active boot partition. I tried to boot multiple times and each time I encountered a black screen with a dash appearing and then disappearing in the top left corner, if I pressed any key on the keyboard I would hear a beep. I tried to reboot multiple times and even deleted the new partition on the Hybrid drive, making a new one and copying the clone. I have my Windows 7 Professional install DVD and put in the 64 bit disc(as you may have guessed I'm running 64 bit Windows 7 Professional). I then exhausted all of the repair options before finally giving up. The clone has all of the drivers that my current hardware setup requires. Re-installing Windows and needing to find all of these again would be a painstakingly long process. Could somebody help me identify the problem?

Comment: What software made the clone image?

Comment: I don't have a clone image, that's one of the problems. It's the whole file system copied onto the external drive.

Comment: You need to edit your question and give specific details of what you did, otherwise no one can answer it in its present form.

Comment: I revised it. If there are any specifics that I left out please inform me.

Comment: Please help, I need this

Comment: "I made a clone of my Windows partition"  HOW THE HELL DID YOU DO THIS, BE SPECIFIC!

Comment: "I made a clone of my Windows partition and stored it on an external hard drive-(I used partition wizard to copy the contents of my hard drive and dump them on the external drive, no disk image).-"

Answer (score -1):

I used Acronis True Image to do just that.  I went from a 5400 RPM drive to a SSHD with 64GB SSD and a 7600 rpm platter.  Boots like lightning.

It is by far the best backup program out there for Windows.  It can restore your whole system to a fresh drive and it will boot just like before.

Forget Clonezilla.  It is very limited, especially with dual-boot systems.